# How to customize the chapter in front of figure page in listoffigures?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, hyperref, cross-referencing, captions

I am using the the packages

```
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[hypcap]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

to include referencable graphics in my work. The structure of the document is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
\title [...]
\maketitle\thispagestyle{empty}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{0}
\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{empty}
\listoffigures
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1} 
\input{Chapter01}
\input{Chapter02}
\input{Chapter03}
\input{Chapter04}
\input{Chapter05}
\input{Chapter06}
\input{Figures}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

. So first there's a title, the toc, then the list of figures, after that six chapters, then the figures themselves and at last the bibliography.

The content of the Figures file follows this scheme:

```
\begin{figure}[htpb]
\centering
\includegraphics{Figure01.jpg}
\caption[Shortcaption01]{Longcaption01}
\label{fig:Figure01}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
%next figure
\begin{figure}[htpb]
\centering
\includegraphics{Figure02.jpg}
\caption[Shortcaption02]{Longcaption02}
\label{fig:Figure02}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
```

Referencing the figures is done with the `\autoref` command, e.g. in Chapter01:

```
Referencing Text~\autoref{fig:Figure01}
```

Oddly Enough, the output this leaves me with is the following:

```
Referencing Text  Figure 6.1
```

Also, in the list of figures, the entry appears as

```
6.1 Shortcaption01                    60
```

If I understand this correctly, then the figures are all believed to belong to chapter six. Firstly this needs to be broken up. I tried inserting

```
\chapter*{Figures}
```

as the first line in the figures file but that did not help. How can I detach the figures from chapter 6?

I want the numbering of the figures to appear according to their references. For example referencing figure fig:Figure02 in chapter 2 should result in:

```
2.2 Shortcaption02                    61
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the [endfloat](http://ctan.org/pkg/endfloat) package.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nomarkers,nolists]{endfloat} % http://ctan.org/pkg/endfloat
\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\mbox{}} % to avoid having each float on its own page

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{One}
Referencing Text~\autoref{fig:Figure01}
\begin{figure}[htpb]
\centering
\caption[Short caption 01]{Long caption 01}
\label{fig:Figure01}
\end{figure}
Referencing Text~\autoref{fig:Figure02}
\begin{figure}[htpb]
\centering
\caption[Short caption 02]{Long caption 02}
\label{fig:Figure02}
\end{figure}

\chapter*{Figures}
\processdelayedfloats % puts all figures in this chapter

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which returns a list of figures of:

[image]

where page 5 is in the starred figures chapter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I cannot get this to work. I guess the problem is that I am using the minipage environment to put multiple graphics on one page. The fff document with all the figures is created, but the figures still have the odd chapter captions, even if I place them in the text and I just get an extra page reading "figures" without content.

Comment: For now I resorted to using `\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}` which gives me serial numbers without chapter prefixes. Read about it here: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=running-nos but that is definitely not the right solution.

Comment: Not really following you yet. If the figures are small enough, they'll share a page without using minipage. But I assume my example compiles correctly for you. Does it fail when you start including your figures, when you start including your chapters, etc.?

Comment: It does not fail, the output simply disregards the input. I'll try extracting all minipages and using the efloatseperator command.

Comment: Taking the graphics out of the minipage environment displays only 2 images on one page instead of three. I included the placeholder chapter in front of the \printbibliography command, because I wanted the bibliography to be the last element of the work, but the images are placed after the bib, disregarding that instruction. Is there some other package besides endfloat serving this purpose?

Comment: For the last question, see `\processdelayedfloats` from section 6 of the `endfloat` documentation. I had misread the requirements from earlier, and I'll try to update my example accordingly. I wouldn't imagine the `minipage` environment is causing a problem, but I've not tried it myself.